Replacing Exterior plywood panels under bay window?
I'd like some help with my bay windows. The second floor base of the window is just plywood, the ground floor is brick. Obviously the plywood has aged and it's starting to warp and pull away etc and I'd like to replace them.
Can anyone give any advice on how to, what to replace with, how to support the window whilst doing this, etc?
Total newbie with this type of stuff so all advice is appreciated. Pictures included and thank you in advance
[

The windows are supported with framing. The plywood is just a skin. Usually old plywood is removed and new installed.  What isn't  apparent is what the exterion final finish is?   Is it stucco?  It doesn't look like just painted plywood, and would not be a norm to have that.  More pics that show the concerning damage would help.

That's great, thank you. Sadly I think it actually is just painted straight on the ply. The bottom level is brick that's been rendered, but the top is literally just plywood with vinyl paint on it. Think it'll be a case of taking off the panels and putting down new ones. Any tips on what to do instead of just painting on direct?

You can consider a Hardie Panel.  A cement composite siding panel that is water resistant and a fire retardant.  It won't warp or split if it gets wet and will take paint extremely well. Installs the same way as plywood.

There's also PVC sheet panel.  Also waterproof and paintable, though a little pricier than Hardie Panel—but only 2/3 the weight if that's important to you.
